# Python, making shallow copy of a list doesn't work with object attributes?

Tags: python, list, object

I am trying to make a shallow copy of a list, this list is stored in an object's attribute. Even though my shallow copy is in a function it doesnt work, I tried

```
copy.copy 

temp = list(actuallist)

temp = actuallist[:]
```

Here is related parts of my current code

This is the object

```
class Game:

    tiles = []
    daleks = []
    rawtile = ""
    height = 20
    width = 20
    tilesize = 32
    gamemap = "default"
    status = 0
    doctor = ""
    screen = ""
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def __init__(self,height,width,tilesize,gamemap):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.tilesize = 32
        self.gamemap = gamemap
        self.status = 0
        size = (tilesize*width, tilesize*height)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Doctor Who vs Daleks")

    def teleportDoctorIn(self,classname):
        self.doctor = classname

    def releaseDalek(self,x):
        self.daleks.append(x)

    def resetDaleks(self):
        daleks = []
```

This is the part where I create a shallow list and change it

```
def updateMap(x,y):
    temp = game.tiles[:]
    """SET DOCTOR COORDS"""
    temp[game.doctor.xpos][game.doctor.ypos] = "X"
    game.doctor.move(x,y)
    temp[game.doctor.xpos][game.doctor.ypos] = "D"
    """LETS MOVE DALEKS"""
```

Turns out i needed to copy.deepcopy() the list.

Comment: Please elaborate on *it doesnt work*. How does it not work? Did you get an error? An unexpected result? Nothing at all?

Comment: Please remove everything from your code that is not needed to showcase the nature of the problem. The question title is very simple, why is the question so long? Please read how to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `temp[game.doctor.xpos][game.doctor.ypos] = "X"` - a shallow copy gave you a new list but it didn't copy the members themselves. The object at `temp[game.doctor.xpos]` is the same object at `game.tiles[game.doctor.xpos]`. I don't know what your intent is, but maybe `copy.deepcopy` is what you want.

Comment: tdelaney, Thanks for the answer. I now understand where i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three techniques make shallow copies of the list. So even though the list itself is unque - and you can do things like adding and removing elements on one without affecting the other - the contained objects are the same. `temp[game.doctor.xpos][game.doctor.ypos] = "X"` changes the contained object which is still held by both lists.

As an example, lets just put some `dict`s in a list and see what happens

```
>>> import copy
>>> d1={1:'one', 2:'two'}
>>> d2={3:'three', 4:'four'}
# create a list then copy it
>>> l1=[d1, d2]
>>> l2=l1[:]

# l1 and l2 are different, but their members are the same
>>> id(l1) == id(l2)
False
>>> id(l1[0]) == id(l2[0])
True

# and if you change the objects in l2, they change l1
>>> l1[0]
{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> l2[0][5]='five'
>>> l1[0]
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 5: 'five'}

# but a deep copy copies the contained objects also so no problem
>>> l3=copy.deepcopy(l1)

# the contained objects are not the same
>>> id(l1[0]) == id(l3[0])
False

# and changing one does not affect the other
>>> l1[0]
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 5: 'five'}
>>> l3[0]
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 5: 'five'}
>>> l3[0][6] = 'six'
>>> 
>>> l1[0]
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 5: 'five'}
>>> l3[0]
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 5: 'five', 6: 'six'}
>>>
```

Comment: how much would deep copying a 20x20 tile list would effect my code? I am making a simple game there charachter moves 1 step at a time, and for every step i will need to make this deep copy

Comment: You can use the `timeit` module to run experiments but I think its only a small effect for a 20x20 array and I wouldn't worry about it. Especially if each step is user intiated where the time it takes to push the `enter` key is large in comparison.

Comment: In my code every move is done with arrow keys, so when user clicks KeyUp, position of the charachter moves 1 square up and then "enemies" inside the map moves 1 block towards to main charachter, then when all the AI and calculations are done, i copy back the tile to show it on screen, i use pygame module to visualize the tiles etc. I am fairly new to programming, this is my first class in python, but i wanted to take a challenge.